# Divisibility properties of linear combinations of binomial coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Let $p$ be a prime and $a_0,\ldots,a_n\geq 0$ be integers. Define
$$
S(a_0,\ldots,a_n)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\binom{n}{k}.
$$

I am trying to find out how much we know about
$$
v_p(S(a_0,\ldots,a_n)),
$$
where $v_p$ is the $p-$adic valuation, or identities involving $S(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$.

Here are a few classical ones, $S(1,x,\ldots,x^n)=(1+x)^n$ and $S(0,1,\ldots,n)=n2^{n-1}$.

Comment: $v_p$ is $p$-adic valuation?

Comment: Yes. I've added that to the original post. Thx!

Comment: It is known is that if $f(x)$ is the exponential generating function of the sequence  $a_n$, then $f(x)\cdot e^x$ is the exponential generating function of $S(a_0,...,a_n)$. This observation brings a lot of classical cases.

Comment: An example with $n=pd$, $\nu_p(S) = 2d-1$, and $a_k$ depending only on $d$ but not $p$ is given in my paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02632

Comment: Needs details or clarity. Arbitrary number can be represented in this form $a_0=N$, $a_1=...=a_n=0.$